# Select a menu item in another application

Tags: vb6, automation, menuitem, windows-api-code-pack

I am using VB6 to try and select a menu item in a sub menu of a third-party application. I can get the ID for the menu item I want to click but now I am not sure how to actually click the button in order to have the related actions run. Here is my code so far:

```
hwnd = FindWindow(psClassname, vbNullString)
If hwnd > 0 Then
Call SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
mwnd = GetMenu(hwnd)
sub_menu = GetSubMenu(mwnd, 0)
button_ID = GetMenuItemID(sub_menu, 0)

Call SetFocus(button_ID)
```

I get the error:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

I've also tried using:

```
Call SendMessage(button_ID, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

but this didn't work either. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ID of the menu item, you can just send/post a `WM_COMMAND` message to its parent that includes the ID. For example:

```
Private Const WM_COMMAND As Long = &H111

SendMessage hwnd, WM_COMMAND, button_ID, ByVal 0&
```

Comment: That worked perfect for the menu items but it doesn't seem to be working when I am trying to send a message to a "ThunderRT6CommandButton". I have the correct ID for the Button and its parent. I'm trying the following code. SendMessage frame_id, WM_COMMAND, button_ID, ByVal 0& and then sleeping for 400ms after. Any ideas?

Comment: This question was about selecting a menu item. If you need to interact with other controls, submit a new question. Thanks.

Comment: SOLVED: Call SendMessage(button_ID, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)